# Plesk Web Admin SE

Tags: aws

I have install the Plesk Web Admin SE Ubuntu for AWS Lightsail. Prior I had no issues but now after 3 months it no longer works and asks for a paid key. I emailed AWS and they said I need to contact you. How can I get this back to the SE edition for  on AWS so i can access my plesk panel again.

Comment: You haven't really given us much information. Based on what you've provided, you need to contact AWS or Plesk support for issues with your deployment and licensing. What reason did they give you to say that this is an Ubuntu issue?

Comment: Let me provide more details:
1. WHen i deploy ubuntu Plesk here - https://tinyurl.com/2h6hdjuc which is a ubunutu stack
2. All is well for 3 months but then when I login i get this.https://tinyurl.com/2gnnoftg
3. The ubunut plesk use to load the se version which allows 3 domains and limited access (thats how it used to  work)
4. But now i have to buy a license so something is wrong in the ubunut setup.

Comment: Plesk requires a license to use. Many providers include the cost of a license in their fee, or they offer a trial or discounted license. But there is nothing you can do in Ubuntu to bypass the license requirement.